# Storing Analytics Locally for processing or store with Google?

Tags: database-design, google-analytics

I want to be able to track clicks on articles and share button clicks on articles to write some sort of method that is able to get popular articles on a particular day.

My question is, should I store this information in my database or should I use Google Analytics to track the information and they grab this information back from Google Analytics to build my trending list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your purpose based on clicks, the best solution is to save information in your database so that you can order the items directly when the page loads.